# How this switch case has unreachable code?

Tags: c#, switch-statement, unreachable-code

I was implementing some generic `IEqualityComparer<T>` `Equal()` method when the code in the switch is unreachable without visible reason for me:

```
public bool Equals(T x, T y)
{
    switch (nameof(T))
    {
        case nameof(Accessory):
            return (x as Accessory).Id == (y as Accessory).Id;//not reachable
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

Someone has a clue?

Comment: next time consider using a if/else instead of a switch case when you have 2 possible cases. You wouldn't have hit this issue :)

Comment: @gumol An `if` statement would have the same problem.

Comment: @RonBeyer you are right! I didn't pay enough attention

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`nameof` evaluates the name of the `T` at *compile time*, so it's a constant string, `"T"`, and thus only the `default` case will ever be taken.

Here's an alternative implementation:

```
public bool Equals(T x, T y)
{
    if (x is Accessory && y is Accessory)
    {
        var ax = x as Accessory;
        var ay = y as Accessory;
        return ax.Id == ay.Id;
    }
    return false;
}
```

C# 7.1 introduces some syntactic sugar:

```
public bool Equals(T x, T y)
{
    if (x is Accessory ax && y is Accessory ay)
    {
        return ax.Id == ay.Id;
    }
    return false;
}
```

(Note that your excerpt returns `false` if both x and y are `null`; I haven't fixed this in my versions.)

Comment: Do you know any way to apply a generic approach that does work?

Comment: If you have a constraint on T (perhaps an interface that Accessory and all other classes that you are going to use with this method), then you can use a switch with a "type pattern". Otherwise, convert the switch to an 'if' statement and use "typeof(T).Name"

Comment: @Eugene I have updated the answer with examples of how to use type identity, rather than the name of the types, to distinguish what the parameters are.

Comment: @JoeSewell I found a better middle ground: `switch (typeof(T).Name) { case nameof(CustomClass): ...` <br> but still appreciate your posted solutions ;)

Comment: "better" how? I'd avoid switching on names. What about `namespace EvilNamespace { class Accessory { ... } } ` Name would still return "Accessory" and would match your `nameof` expression. Better check the actual type with is/as since you're casting to it anyways

Answer (score 0):

Can use this. This checks for null x and y:

```
public bool Equals(T x, T y)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
            if (ReferenceEquals(x, null)) return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(y, null)) return false;


    if (x.GetType()

 != y.GetType()) return false;
            return x.Id == y.Id;
        }
```